# Leftover-files after deinstallation of Debian package with own update-mechanism

Tags: ubuntu, packaging, deb, dpkg, debhelper

I have a Debian package which has to update some files. These files will exist after a uninstallation of the Debian package. I want to remove them together with my package, when i call *apt-get remove*.

If i add the updated files to

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.list
```

they will be removed.

**Update:**
I'll remove the folder in the postrm.debhelper script with

> rm -rf folder

But it feels not right. ;)

Comment: Please make your question more clear. Are you shipping the files that need to change *with* the package, or do those files belong to other packages, or are they not owned by any packages? Do you *want* them to be removed on package uninstall or not? Making direct changes to `/var/lib/dpkg/info/$package.list` is almost certainly not a good idea.

Comment: The files i want to remove belong to no other programs. They should be removed with the package uninstall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would say that this sounds like somewhat improper behavior for a package, deleting files on uninstall that existed before install, and I'd strongly recommend against doing anything of the sort in a package meant for use by the general public. However, if it's for private use, and the relevant people understand what it does, it should be fine.

Removing the files in the prerm or postrm sounds like the best answer. But be sure you don't perform the `rm` unconditionally; the prerm and postrm can be called in several circumstances other than total package removal.

The postrm is preferable over the prerm, unless you want to make completely sure that the files will be removed *before* the package's own contents are removed from the filesystem.

In a postrm, I would suggest doing something like

```
case "$1" in
    purge|disappear)
        rm -rf $your_folder
esac
```

You could add `remove` to `purge` and `disappear` there, if you want the files to be removed even when the package is "removed" as opposed to "purged" ("remove" means the package's configuration files will be kept; this usually implies a chance of the package being installed again later).

A postrm will also be called on a normal package upgrade, or when an upgrade or initial install fails (actions `upgrade`, `failed-upgrade`, `abort-install`, and `abort-upgrade`). See Debian Policy for a detailed description of how and when those are used. You almost definitely don't want to perform the `rm` in those cases.

Comment: The files doesn't exist before the package is installed. The installed package, updated some files, which will not be removed. But with youre hints i will add remove and purge for removing the whole folder, which i create while installing the debian package. Even some files get into this folder get updated, i want they be cleaned, when the package will uninstalled.